# Status of Our Community Blog

Tags: discussion, blog

What is the status of our [community blog](http://cstheory.blogoverflow.com/)?  There haven't been any new posts in about 5 months.

Comment: I hope we finally hold that [essay contest](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/1429/1037) to spur activity.I am to blame for some of the lack of activity: I've had a nearly complete post sitting in prep for over a year, now.

Comment: Paging @joe-fitzsimons

Comment: I don't know what to say other than that I've let this slip. Work has been insanely busy, and I'm finding I have less time to spend on the blog and on soliciting submissions than I expected. If somebody with more energy and more time on their hands is interested in taking over from me, then I will happily vacate the position, though I guess the actual selection of a new blog co-editor would be community driven.

Comment: I should add that I am open to any suggestions for increasing submissions, and the essay contest certainly seems like a good idea.

Comment: fyi in case anyone hadnt noticed, possible topic, this recent question on [interactive computation vs CT thesis](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/12377/applicability-of-church-turing-thesis-to-interactive-models-of-computation) got an unexpectedly surprisingly awful lot of mileage, a real lightning rod topic, seems like it could deserve a blog, also scott aaronson blogged about it & his answer currently has a startling 41 votes, ~3x the question. lance fortnow has commented on it on his blog & wrote essay on subj. ACM focus on the issue.. many CS researchers implicated...

Comment: another idea for a blog entry — profile many of most famous/"senior" participants on the list (not nec measured by site points, but also TCS community visibility) and highlights of their accomplishments both on/off the site. & anything else they'd like/be willing to add. ie what they like about the site, what direction they'd like the site to go in, their current research directions & how they might mesh with the site, etc

Comment: just noticed this great SIGACT news writeup from awhile back by [suresh et al](http://www.cs.utah.edu/~suresh/cstheory.pdf) accessable from the "about" page of the blog, which highlights questions, activity, senior researchers etc. if something like this could be done every 6mo or yr for the blog, think many would find it highly apropos/readable

Comment: see also [blog signup sheet](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/1196/cstheory-blog-announcement-and-signup-sheet)

Comment: fyi I have long been using the [chat](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/9446/theory-salon) as a informal blog/twitter like medium.... seemingly a good place to strategize about the blog if anyone around ever again cares....

Answer (score 5):

Thanks, Suresh, for emailing me about this question.  I've been busy, concentrating on other things, and haven't logged into TCS for months.  I haven't posted new content in my personal blog either (though I've written a series of unpublished posts that may or may not ever see the light of day).

I'm not in a position to generate new content right now for the community blog right now, but I'm happy to help others do it, like suggesting how to polish something, or helping to recruit a faculty member specialist to take a look at a technical post that a grad student produces.

In an extremely generous sense of the word, there have been submissions to the blog over the last few months.  No one knows about them but me, because they have all been spammy emails I haven't forwarded.  I don't know why I got the mails and not Joe, but maybe he has received some he never sent to me.  I must admit, the researcher in me would like to know if the woman who wrote, "I will pay you $50 if you let me write a post on..." would ever have come through with the money.

That's all I've got for now, but I'll start checking Meta regularly again, to see what others think/suggest.

Comment: I never seem to get the submissions. Not sure why.

Comment: @joe / aaron... do you have access to hit statistics for the blog? wondering what the traffic is; if it is more than negligible, it could be some incentive to write for it

Answer (score 2):

I could write a post about my attempts to prove that portal 2 is PSPACE complete.

Comment: wondering, what happened to well-supported [short introductions to topological quantum computation and the basics of quantum computation](http://meta.cstheory.stackexchange.com/a/1198/7884)? went thru entire blog hunting for it (unfortunately there is no index by contributor, which would be basic/nice); apparently never materialized

Comment: @vzn They deemed my introduction too basic for the site.

Comment: looks like the 6mo blogless milestone is gonna come & go. [without seeing the QM entry] seems if it was not erroneous, my vote is that its better than nothing =) ps for others, heres the [Portal video game question](http://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/11961/complexity-of-portal-2)

Answer (score -2):

Could I write something? Or are there specific requirements that I wouldn't meet?